# Layout define in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

Now, I'm building an application to learn english. In my app, when user have a long tap with a word, I want to show a view with content is meaning of dictionary which user downloaded. It's like `dictionary of iOS`, when you have a long tap with a word, iOS will show to you a option the `define`, after you choose it, iOS will show to you a view with definition of that word. So, I want to create a view like `dictionary of iOS` but could I custom content that `dictionary view` or create a another view and add it to current view.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Can you rephrase it? Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: I edited my question, hope you help me! Is it clear? If u don't understand my proplem I will edit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do there are essentially three steps to what you need to do:

1. Recognize that the word was tapped. If it is something like UILabel you can just add a gesture recognizer to it (see *UITapGestureRecognizer* for more). If you are tapping a word within something like UITextView it's gonna be more complicated than that.
2. Display a special *UIView* (the little pop up one) at the place tapped with a *Define* button or something
3. When that button/view is tapped, display another view with translation/explanation of that word

If you want a more detailed answer you are gonna have to be way more specific than your current question.